# jQuery .on() delegated mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to delegate multiple events using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

This is the syntax for one delegated event:

```
$(document).on('mouseeenter','.foo', function(){});
```

And here is the syntax for multiple events (not delegated):

```
$('.foo').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        //stuff
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        //stuff
    }
});
```

I was wondering if there was a more succinct way to do this other then:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.foo', function(){})
           .on('mouseleave', '.foo', function(){});
```

It's not a big deal if I have to do it that way, I'm more curious about it than anything.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah, looks it. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. According to comments in the other question, it is not easy to search for this topic in the first place.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        //stuff
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        //stuff
    }
}, '.foo');
```

Comment: This is better than live() which is deprecated for new versions :)